# Set up Azure Service Fabric cluster on managed disks

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Does anybody know how to set up Service Fabric cluster with VMs on managed disks(both OS and Data)?  I would be very interested to know how to do this using template config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change VMSS api version to `2016-04-30-preview` and storageProfile to this:

```
"storageProfile": {
    "imageReference": {
        "publisher": "[parameters('vmImagePublisher')]",
        "offer": "[parameters('vmImageOffer')]",
        "sku": "[parameters('vmImageSku')]",
        "version": "[parameters('vmImageVersion')]"
    },
    "osDisk": {
        "createOption": "FromImage"
        "managedDisk": {
            "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS" 
   # defauls to Standard_LRS,
   # you can choose to pick Premium_LRS if your VM size supports premium storage 
   # or you can omit this node completely if you need standard storage
        }
    }
}
```

Storage Accounts are redundant when using managed disks (you don't need them, Azure handles that for you).

Comment: That might be a typo, I'd imagine it has to be typed as "Standard" instead of "Standart".

Comment: you can edit the answer, but yes, its due to the fact that in russian its `standart`. I always confuse those :)

Comment: Now in api version 2018-06-01 you can set storageAccountType to StandardSSD_LRS