# Azure Service Fabric disk full

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have an Azure Service Fabric running on Azure. When we created the cluster, all data are stored on D: drive which is a temp folder with low disk space. It looks like Service Fabric is also using the D: drive to write his logs and those logs takes half of the space.

At some time we run out of space on some nodes in the cluster. We free up space but the problem will probably come back very soon.

Does everyone know how we could safely reconfigure Service Fabric to store data elsewhere ? Could we do that on existing cluster or do we have to reinstall a new cluster ? Could we mount drives from Azure storage and use that for SF logs or storing our data ?

Comment: Maybe you can create a new cluster, using managed disks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117317/set-up-azure-service-fabric-cluster-on-managed-disks

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue for that instance, you can **reset your cluster**. So it will clear cache and free up the memory for service execution.

**Edit 1:**

Here I found msdn link to change settings of service fabric. This might help.
**[Customize service fabric cluster settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings)**

(Not really an answer, but I cannot comment since I am under 50 points :))